About how to continue acquiring information of a specific BLE device with CoreBluetooth on iOS
We have confirmed that there are no duplicate questions, but if there are, we apologize for the inconvenience, but please let us know if there is a page that has solved a similar question.
I have several questions, so please give me some advice.
First, iOS does not allow you to check the device address like Android. I think it is a well-known fact for all developers that iOS generates a UUID type Peripheral Identifier (ID) from the advertisement data received from a BLE device.
When I contacted Apple's developer support, I was told that iOS does not allow persistent monitoring of specific device information through scanned advertising data.
I believe this means that iOS cannot use advertised data to monitor sensor values ​​(blood pressure or temperature) on a particular BLE device.
The reason for this is that iOS is designed so that cached advertisement data cannot permanently identify a specific device.
This means that a cache is only unique while it is held in temporary memory, and a new ID is generated each time it leaves the cache.
If so, in order to permanently monitor sensor values ​​of a specific BLE device in an iOS app, is it necessary to read them using GATT communication?
If that's true, I don't know how iOS can recognize a specific device and make a continuous connection.
This is because, as mentioned earlier, advertising data changes and there is no way to recognize a specific device.
If you use Android, you can save the device address of the BLE device in the application and connect it whenever you want. (Only if the device address is not a random address.)
However, in the case of iOS, it is not possible for the application to obtain the device address, so there is no way to know whether the ID that changes every time is the BLE device you want to monitor.
Therefore, the following questions.
① Is it not possible for iOS to monitor information from a specific device using BLE using only advertisement data?
②If GATT communication is required, is pairing required to connect to a specific device?
Ideally, if possible, I would like to be able to continuously connect to a specific device on iOS without pairing or bonding.
The second question is: What kind of design approach is needed to achieve this?
One of the last-ditch measures I came up with is to include the unchanging BLE device-specific data in the advertisement data in ManufacturingData and have it sent from the BLE device.
The app continues to monitor data from specific devices by frequently checking for unique data and ID changes.
However, the advertisement data already includes a packet that stores the device address, so it seems wrong to have to go to the trouble of utilizing ManufactureData without using it.
We apologize for the inconvenience, but please tell us how to perform smooth BLE communication with a specific BLE device on iOS.

When Core Bluetooth provides the details of a peripheral, it includes an identifier. This identifier is unique to that peripheral on that iOS device but it is fixed (it may change if the device is erased, I am not sure).   You can always use that identifier on the specific iOS device to identify that peripheral. You cannot provide that identifier to another device and expect it to be able to use it.  You can also access data from the advertisement, but only while your app is in the foreground.

thank you for your reply. I also want to believe your words that "Identifier is unique and fixed."
However, when I contacted Apple's developer support, I received the following reply:
"UUIDs (probably Identifiers) do not document why or when they change. They change regardless of the state of the cache. All you need to know is that they change over time. ”
I think this means that the Identifier is not a unique number to permanently identify the BLE device.

It is not guaranteed unique indefinitely, no.  In practice, however, I have an app that stores the peripheral identifier in order to reconnect to it when it comes into range.  It has remained unchanged for well over a year.  It is the best you are going to get. Now, there may be a difference in behaviour between a peripheral you actually connect to regularly, and one that you simply receive advertising packets for. I can see that the identifier may change more frequently in that case for privacy reasons.

As Rob said in his answer, unless you have a need for multiple devices to receive data and your peripheral doesn't support multiple connections , you will be much better off using a connection rather than simply trying to read data from the advertisement.  Connections will work while your app is in the background and iOS can relaunch your app if a peripheral with a pending connection comes back into range.

Thank you very much for your valuable information.
I don't know the reason, but if there is a case where the "Peripheral ID" generated by iOS does not change for more than a year, then there will be no need to take measures to include the device address in the advertisement data (ManufactureData packet).
Is it an app on the market? If you don't mind, could you tell me?
The only concern I have is that in order to get assurance of that fact, I think I would need to conduct a demonstration experiment in my own development environment.

Thanks to Paulw11 and Rob's advice, we found that systems that use advertising data for monitoring are not recommended due to both battery and implementation difficulties.
On the other hand, the design I am envisioning is the development of an iOS app that receives data from multiple (20 or more) BLE devices (servers) and monitors it on a single iPhone (client).
Therefore, based on their advice, I think that a GATT connection is appropriate in the above case, but is this judgment correct?

First, the normal way to do what you're describing is to connect to the device and subscribe to the GATT characteristic. That's exactly how BLE is designed to work. Bluetooth devices generally use random and changing addresses. This is a significant privacy feature of BLE. It sounds like you're building your own devices and aren't doing that, which is ok, but most of BLE is built around the assumption that the advertising address changes regularly. There is a system called "resolvable addresses" that allows you to determine that a device's random address is actually a device you've paired with before. But this only generally applies once you pair.
So to your questions:

Is it not possible for iOS to monitor information from a specific device using BLE using only advertisement data?

As you noted, it is certainly possible using manufacturer data, and I've built systems that do that. If you like, you can even advertise your private address there. It's not a problem. However, it also requires that you scan using the CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey option, or you'll only ever get one advertisement. This isn't a great design though. It's not great for battery life and it's kind of fighting the system.

If GATT communication is required, is pairing required to connect to a specific device?

Yes. But also it doesn't really matter if your device implements Just Works security, which is really common. Just Works is extremely transparent to the user. The resulting peripheralID is pretty stable, though not promised to be completely stable (and I've seen them change). If it's important to know which is which, I generally like to read the serial number via Device Information Service just to be sure.
The advantage of connecting and using GATT is that you can subscribe to the characteristic to be notified every time it changes. This works even in the background, unlike reading from advertising. It can even automatically re-launch the app if a device comes in range. Subscriptions to characteristics are very power efficient and powerful. If the device supports it, that's how you want to send information around.
The main reason IMO to use advertising to send information is if you need multiple clients (phones) to all be able to see the data at the same time and your device can't support multiple connections. Then using manufacturer data is a reasonable option. But it's pretty limited and not ideal for battery life.

question -- GATT can, in my simple understanding, be used without PAIRing, assuming you connect to the device. right?  I connect to devices and and get notify and indications from these.  Maybe I don't understand the context.

It depends on how the security is setup. Many devices have "Just Works" security, which will cause them to pair transparently. But it is true that some devices do not even have that, and don't require even an implicit pairing step. But for devices with Just Works, the user won't need to do anything.

Thank you for accurately understanding my clumsy question.
My explanation was insufficient. Certainly, the BLE device I am assuming is communicating with a Public Address type.
The case I am envisioning is a system that monitors information from 20 or more BLE devices using a single iOS app.
And in order to monitor them, you need to accurately identify which ones are which.
Based on Paulw11 and Rob advice, I can see that in my case the recommended method is to make a GATT connection and read the information.

①Please let me confirm. I understand that to establish a Resolvable Address, bonding is required after pairing. Rob explained how to obtain the serial number via the Device Information Service after that to identify which BLE device is which. The serial number is read via the Device Information Service to cover the unstable nature of the Peripheral ID, but if the Peripheral ID has changed, it will not be possible to connect. In that case, does that mean that you connect to all the advertising data emitted by surrounding BLE devices one by one and check the serial number?

②Next, as far as I have researched, BLE has no upper limit on the number of peripherals that can be connected to one central.
However, the BLE specification recommends connecting when necessary and disconnecting when not necessary.
So, in the case I am considering this time, for example, the app will connect to more than 20 devices simultaneously only when it is in the foreground. And does this mean using the characteristic property notify?

For 1, yes, you would connect to any devices that appear possible to be your devices. (So at a least advertising the services you are interested in.) For 2, correct. You would make 20 connections, and subscribe using setNotifyValue(). This does require that the devices support notifications/indications, which are BLE features (but they're very common features, so most devices will support them).
